# Connect data points around missing data with different style of line on graph

Tags: charts, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I have an libreoffice-calc spreadsheet with some results of daily measurements. Some days are missed for some reasons.

I want to create a graph showing this data, and I want to highlight all missed data parts. E.g. use solid line to connect existing data points and dotted line to connect through missing data points, or using different colors for that.

Example of what I want:
[image: chart I want]

In [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/332718/) I found a way to connect missing data points - but how to highlight those connections? Setting "Format Data Series" -> "Plot options" -> "Continue line" option makes all graph solid, so you can't assume which parts of graph are showing existing or missing data.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't do this inside LO Calc. But you can "postprocess" the chart, e.g. with Inkscape, after exporting the chart as SVG. There, you can split the data lines in single pieces and format them manually.

Comment: Another manual option would be to choose "Leave Gap" so the gaps would be apparent, and then use the Draw tool to add dotted lines of the same color on top of the chart.