# How can I supress zero values in a LibreOffice line line chart?

Tags: charts, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm making a line chart counting users of various releases of a piece of software over the years. This is a very spiky line chart, where as new versions come into existence and then retire, lines should start arbitrarily along the X axis. However, instead, since there is a "0" in my data for the periods where that version didn't even exist yet, I instead get all values starting at 0,0, with a flat line along the bottom.

It's not a big deal, but it's irritating my sense of chart aesthetics. How can I suppress this? I found various options to not *show* zero-value cells in the data itself (either on-screen or when printing), but they don't seem to affect the line chart.

Comment: Can you edit the data series to start later?

Comment: You mean, just delete all the initial zero values manually? I guess I could. That feels pretty hackish, though.

Comment: I think you need at least one zero value or it looks weird. http://i.stack.imgur.com/SYfoU.png

Comment: Relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/332718/how-do-i-create-a-line-graph-which-ignores-zero-values

Comment: @Burgi: Good point in general, although in my case the values go up to over 100k so the difference between 0 and 1 is invisibile.

Comment: And, to elaborate on why I don't want to edit the data series: the data itself is coming from an automated process. The less manual munging I need to do, the better. I could set up a filter _before_ I import the data, but... it sure would be nicer to just do it with the spreadsheet.

Comment: FWIW, I just went with deleting the values for now. The suggested duplicate may help someone else. I'm leaving this open in the case something comes up in the future.